# Mac OS - Installed Python 3 via Anaconda, but no feed back of which python3

Tags: anaconda, python-3.6

As a Python beginner, I installed Python 3 via Anaconda, and have successfully installed it in my Mac laptop. I have no problem to use Python 3 if I launch Jupyter notebook, but I cannot locate it in the terminal.

Specifically, if is type in:

```
$ which python
```

I got the feedback of

```
/usr/bin/python
```

but if I type in

```
$ which python3
```

There is no feedback at all. Just curious if I have missed anything.

Comment: Go to the terminal and type 'python3' (without quotes) and let me know what your output is.

Answer (score 0):

When you install a new environment with Anaconda with a specific version of Python, that version of Python will be accessible only if you activate the Anaconda's environment.

If you want to access to your python 3 of your environnement from the terminal, you need to activate it :

```
source activate my_env
```

Then you can write "which python3"

For example, on my computer, you can see two different versions of Python depending on the environnement I use or the version installed on my Mac.

```
// On my mac
which python3

>> /Users/michaelcaraccio/anaconda/bin/python3
```

Then when I activate the env :

```
which python3

>> /Users/michaelcaraccio/anaconda/envs/TM/bin/python3
```

If you need more information, don't hesitate to ask :)